# 2 Pickers in 1 ViewController? Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get 2 pickers into one view controller and im really struggling at the minute. I've created two arrays and I thought I had linked them both up, however it appears both pickers and fetching data from the same data source. The first picker should change the data selected (myLabel.text) which it does, but it also changes the career selected which id like the second picker to do. If I could have some help on this matter it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I have also tried searching similar issues that other people are facing, but for some reason i just can't link it to my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLabel.text = @"Use the scroller above...";

    datePickerView.delegate = self;
    CareerPickerView.dataSource = self;

    _pickerViewArray = @[@"Before September 2012",@"After September 2012"];

    CareerViewArray = @[@"This is choice 1",@"This is choice 2"];        
    CareerPickerView.delegate = self;
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *dateSelected = [_pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *careerSelected = [CareerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
    myLabel.text = dateSelected;
    startingsalary.text = careerSelected;

    if ([dateSelected isEqualToString:@"Before September 2012"])
        myLabel.text = @"Before September 2012";

    if ([dateSelected isEqualToString:@"After September 2012"])
        myLabel.text = @"After September 2012";
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return _pickerViewArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return _pickerViewArray[row];
}

@end
```

Comment: In all picker view delegate methods, you need to treat two pickerViews and data source separately, perhaps by using tag is enough for you case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check which Picker is calling the `delegate` in the method `pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Check which `UIPickerView` is now calling that method and do whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain both the arrays and the picker view that is being selected properly.

Follow below code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
       if(pickerView == datePickerView)
       {
          NSString *dateSelected = [_pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
          myLabel.text = dateSelected;
       }
       else if(pickerView == CareerPickerView)
       {
          NSString *careerSelected = [CareerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
          startingsalary.text = careerSelected;
       }
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(pickerView == datePickerView)
    {
      return _pickerViewArray.count;
    }
    else if(pickerView == CareerPickerView)
    {
      return CareerViewArray.count;
    }
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  if(pickerView == datePickerView)
  {
     return _pickerViewArray[row];
  }
  else if(pickerView == CareerPickerView)
  {
    return CareerViewArray[row];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I then go about populating the career picker? It looks like now when I change the date selected picker it's now not changing the expecting starting salary which is good, but I now have nothing in the career array it just seems blank?

Comment: There is a typo in `numberOfRowsInComponent`, I've edited it.

Comment: @Stewartps If your array is already filled in viewDidLoad, then just reload the components of picker view like     [CareerPickerView reloadAllComponents]; and if thats doesn't work try to alloc array with objects just before the pacer view is presented.

Answer (score 0):

Apply tags to your UIPickerview and in each delegate method compare picker with tag make sure you are returning objects within braces which is differentiated for tags